# Javascript unable to reference Hashmap using string name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, hashmap

I have multiple Hashmap in my javavscript code and I'm trying to dynamically load the relevant map according to the name passed to the function.

The problem is when I pass the value as string value it actually tries to get the keys of the string rather than the object which it refers to.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5g9w40L/) properly illustrates my problem.

`Line 13` gives the expected output whereas `Line 14` creates keys out of the string name.

Comment: make another map that associates names with the related object or abuse that global variables are properties on `window` for this special case

Comment: Object.keys(window[name]), however your code doesnt make sense

Comment: @Jonasw I'm not sure what exactly you mean? I tried to add the relevant part of my code to the fiddle

Comment: @anonn023432 its still worse to build up variable names directly. that doesnt make sense.

Comment: @Jonasw so if I have a situation where I have five object names as `PROP_ONE`, `CROP_ONE`, `DROP_ONE` and so what would be the best way in your opinion to call them dynamically? Or do you mean I should've separate functions for every name?

Comment: @anonn023432 no, put them into an array, then get PROP[0] ...

Comment: @Jonasw okay that makes sense, I'm actually going to follow this advice because I don't want to call the global `window` if it's not required. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Its basically the difference between:

```
Object.keys(PROP_ONE)
```

and

```
 Object.keys("PROP_ONE")
```

While the first is an identifier resolved to an object, the second one is just a string. not more. You may access it using bracket notation due to the fact that its part of window:

```
Object.keys(window["PROP_ONE"])
```

---

Disclaimer:

All in all, dynamic keys should just be used if really neccessary. They make your code slower and more buggy.